# Modifying existing AssociateWith<> in Linq-to-Sql

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have some linq-to-sql where we use AssociateWith<> to limit some of the records to only those for a particular user. I might -in some cases- want to limit those records to a specific date too. Once I have created my option.AssociateWith(....), can I modify it? If so, how? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.dataloadoptions.aspx) says that there is no possibility to achieve this keeping the DataContext instance (see the Rules section). So dispose the context and reassign the DataLoadOptions.

Comment: I want to modify the AssociateWith BEFORE it's assigned to the context. In other words, I want to be able to build my query one step at a time: I know the first WHERE, but depending on how the user sets various fields, I want to be able to add more WHERE clauses.